# Using IN operator with case when in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to run a case when statement that works with the `IN` operator - so that when the value (or values) `URL` are provided to the IN clause, it will perform the case when giving the values a 1 or a Null when they match either a URL or a group of URL's that are provided.

I'm rather stuck on how to actually use the `IN` operator for the case when operation. I want to be able to provide multiple values where it has url - rather than one. Is this possible?

My code is the following:

```
create temp table ag_table as 
   with sq AS(select id, business, 
   cat1, cat2, channel, call_reason, 
   COUNT(case cat1 when url then 1 else null end) 
   over (partition by subject 
order by 
time range between 604800 preceding
and current row) as count 
from table_name
where table_name.start >= start and table.end_time <= end
)
```

To note I am using SQLite

Comment: `when url`? That should include a boolean expression; something like `WHEN url = 'abc'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax for the CASE expression:

```
COUNT(case when category1 IN (url1, url2, ...) then 1 end)
```

There is no need for `else null` (null is the default value when there is no else).
The same can be achieved by:

```
SUM(category1 IN (url1, url2, ...))
```

Comment: So if i pass in multiple values at the point (url1,url2) then 1 end - it will perform the case when statement as like if there was only one value passed in? e.g. just (url1)

Comment: If `category1` matches any of the values in the list `(url1, url2, ...)` it will be counted.